# How can I hide dataset labels in Chart.js v2?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I have the following code to create a graph using Chart.js v2.1.3:

```
var ctx = $('#gold_chart');
var goldChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: dates,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'I want to remove this Label',
            data: prices,
            pointRadius: 0,
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    }
});
```

The code looks simple, but I cannot remove the label from the graph. I tried a lot of solutions I found online, but most of them use Chart.js v1.x.

How can I remove the dataset labels?

Answer (score 343, accepted):

Just set the `label` and `tooltip` options like so

```
...
options: {
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
           label: function(tooltipItem) {
                  return tooltipItem.yLabel;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g19220r6/

Comment: works like charm, thanks. by the way, how to change the gradient color of the line chart?

Comment: You mean, how to use a gradient as the borderColor / backgroundColor. Just create one on the context and use that when initializing - see http://jsfiddle.net/g9h6gtvx/

Comment: What if I want to use it on one dataset but not on the other one

Comment: It works! just one question, where did you find all these options?

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer works in the latest v2.9.3. http://jsfiddle.net/hwtysf64/

Comment: This works for me in 3.4.1, by setting `options.plugins.tooltip.callbacks.label` to the function.

Comment: this didn't work for me . adding the code within plugins works not in options

Comment: Note that in Chart JS 3 it's tooltip, not tooltips. This tripped me up for a minute.

Answer (score 212):

As of 2021, the namespace has changed from `options.legend` to `options.plugins.legend`. This simple code worked for me -

```js
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
}
```

[Documentation reference](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#configuration-options)

Comment: ```js
options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 54):

add:

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
```

in the starting of your script code;

Comment: Simple and works perfectly. I noticed the accepted answer was breaking some things.

Comment: In React, I did this `import { Chart } from "react-chartjs-2";

Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
`

Comment: Doesn't this disable it for all charts, in all pages where `Chart` is being used?

Answer (score 35):

## New Solution ChartJS v3.1.1

The above solution is correct for previous versions of chart js prior to v3.1 for v3.1.1 use the following

```
 ...
 options: {
  plugins:{
   legend: {
    display: false
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: This also work in v4.2.1

Answer (score 19):

For those who want to remove the actual axis labels and not just the legend in 2021 **(Chart.js v.3.5.1)**. Note: this also removes the axes.

```js
const chartWrap = document.querySelector('.chart-wrap')
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

chartWrap.appendChild(canvas)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Your', 'axis', 'labels'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Your legend label',
                data: [1, 3, 2],
                backgroundColor: '#54ACEF'
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            legend: false // Hide legend
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                display: false // Hide Y axis labels
            },
            x: {
                display: false // Hide X axis labels
            }
        }   
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="chart-wrap" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-Wt1bJGtlnMtGP0dqNFH1xlkLBNpEodaiQ8ZN5JLA5wpc1sUlk/O5uuOMNgvzddzkpvZ9GLyYNa8w2s7rqiTk5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: This does not remove the axis labels but the entire axes togehter with the grid

Comment: Oh dang, you're right @LeeLenalee. I should probably rephrase. Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 13):

You can also put the tooltip onto one line by removing the "title":

```
this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: this.props.horizontal ? 'horizontalBar' : 'bar',
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: tooltipItem => `${tooltipItem.yLabel}: ${tooltipItem.xLabel}`, 
                title: () => null,
            }
        },
    },
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

It's just as simple as adding this:

```
legend: {
    display: false,
}
```

Or if you want you could use this other option which should also work:

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;``
```

Comment: options: {
        legend: {
display: false,
}}
It helps to write which block to put it in (this is basically the problem with the documentation)

Comment: For **v3.0.0+**: `options: {  plugins: { legend: { display: false } }  }`

Answer (score 9):

```
new Chart('idName', {
      type: 'typeChar',
      data: data,
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. consider adding a brief explanation next to the code

Answer (score 3):

Replace options with this snippet, will fix for Vanilla JavaScript Developers

```js
options: {
            title: {
                text: 'Hello',
                display: true
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### [⬆ v3.0.0 and after](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta.7)

```js
...
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
}
```

### ⬇ Before v3.0.0

```js
...
options: {
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me also needed to remove x-axis and y-axis labels. for that use:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      display: false, // Hide x-axis label
    },
    y: {
      display: false, // Hide y-axis label
    }
  }
}
```